# Фон не должен перекрывать текст

Tags: css3, html5, background

У меня была проблема как у Алексея:[background-color поверх background-image в body](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/537931/background-color-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%85-background-image-%D0%B2-body?answertab=votes#tab-top)
Благодаря ответу Hochru она была решена, но сразу же появилась следующая. Как сделать чтоб background-color не накрывался на текст?
z-index не помог

```css
.body {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 620px;
  background-image: url(https://img.fonwall.ru/mid/zi/kanchanaburi-tailand-vodopad-kaskad-c4gb.jpg);
background-size:cover;
}

.body::before {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba( 255, 255, 255, .5);
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <p>Текст</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавить тексту `z-index` выше, соответственно задав при этом `position:relative`:

```css
body {
position: relative;
min-height: 620px;
background-image: url(https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/plant-growing-picture-id510222832?k=6&m=510222832&s=612x612&w=0&h=Pzjkj2hf9IZiLAiXcgVE1FbCNFVmKzhdcT98dcHSdSk=);
}

body::before {
content:'';
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
left: 0;
top: 0;
position: absolute;
background-color: rgba( 255, 255, 255, .5);
z-index: 1;
}

p {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <p>Текст</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Пфф. Все оказалось довольно просто. Спасибо, и простите за столь легкий вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

пасиба, за ответ. добавлю от себя, когда надо решить вопрос с наплыванием на многих элементах, просто сделай отдельный класс для различных задач. например 5 div блоков можно обернуть в 6 (который будет отвечать только за фон)

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).